# Counterexample that a program computes HALT(x, x)

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

Hello everyone I am having trouble solving this exercise question. I don't get it what do they mean by providing the value of input x ? It would be highly appreciated if anyone helps to clarify the question at least.

Suppose it is claimed that a program computes HALT(x, x).  Give a counterexample that shows the claim to be false. That is, give an input x for which P gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Suppose I come to you with a shiny black box and I tell you "if you input a program x into my black box, it will answer with the result of HALT(x,x)". You are skeptical and you know that I tend to lie about my black boxes; in order to prove me wrong, try to prove that there must exist an input on which my black box gives a wrong answer.

Comment: Not only is it very difficult for Stef's machine to always give the right answer (especially if X with input x continues running for a very, very long time),  not only can you show there _must_ be an X where the output is wrong, but you can practically find a program where x where the black box will _always_ give the wrong answer.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think you can’t prove it for a physical box.